# Why is there a wait problem in cypress delete

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, cypress, angular-test

```js
    cy.server();
    cy.route(
      "DELETE",
      "...."
    ).as("ticket");
    cy.visit("....");

    cy.wait("@ticket");
    cy.get("@ticket").then((xhr: any) => {
      console.log("deneme");
      // expect(check.status).to.eq(204);
      // expect(check.method).to.eq("GET");
    });
```

There is no problem with POST GET and PATCH operations. But in the DELETE operation, I get the following problem.
[image]

Comment: does cypress match any response on your route?

Comment: @AlexIzbas When I do manual deletion, it throws the request above and works properly.

Comment: why do you do it manually? you have to simulate it by cypress, so `route` will listen for your URL during the run